# ASP.NET CompositeScript Path results in 404

Tags: javascript, asp.net

If I use the CompositeScript feature of the ASP.NET ScriptManager/ScriptManagerProxy controls, I cannot get the Path attribute to work:

My code

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="scriptProxy2" runat="server">
  <CompositeScript Path="~/Includes/Javascript/Combined.js">
    <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Includes/Javascript/MyFile1.js" />
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Includes/Javascript/MyFile2.js" />
    </Scripts>
  </CompositeScript>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

My page gets the correct script tag in it:

```
<script src="../Includes/Javascript/Combined.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But of course, that file doesn't exist and so the browser gets a 404.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you specified source scripts to get combined using `ScriptReference` tag - see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488552.aspx).

**EDIT**: After using reflector, I discovered that if you use specify `Path` attribute, the script combining does not happen - it just emits script ref to the path specified (modifying as per release/debug mode and culture (if localization is enabled)). After googling around, found that intended use of path property is to work around url limit of 1024 characters. From [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.compositescriptreference.aspx):

> The number of script references that a
>   CompositeScriptReference instance can
>   contain is limited by the size of the
>   resulting URL. The URL cannot be
>   longer than 1024 characters.
>
> If you have to work around this
>   limitation, you have two options. The
>   first option is to reduce the number
>   of ScriptReference objects that the
>   composite script contains. The second
>   option is to manually combine the
>   scripts into a single static file. In
>   that case, you can set the Path
>   property to the location of the static
>   file.

I have also stumbled upon [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/06/12/script-reference-profiler.aspx) where there is a wealth of information in comments section. One such comment clearly states that

> You can combine multiple physical
>   script files using that feature, but
>   we really don't recommend it as there
>   is some server overhead related to
>   file monitoring. What you're
>   describing is much better handled by
>   "building" your scripts at compile
>   time instead of doing the combination
>   at runtime. The feature really is for
>   application developers who want to
>   combine existing scripts from various
>   components that they use in their
>   application.

So in summary, I think that how you intend use the combine script is neither supported nor recommended. I will suggest that you use build time script combining - below resources will help you in achieving the same:

http://encosia.com/2009/05/20/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/

Look at mashing feature in [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) add-in: http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/18/chirpy-attains-godlike-abilities-in-version-1-0-0-4/#mash

Comment: Yes, I should have been more detailed to begin with, but I have now updated my code sample to show scripts being added.  And the documentation does say that I can give the script a name, under the "Assigning a File Name to a Composite Script" section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488552.aspx#50c4c2a9-bbbd-4bda-8413-c3d1c43fe37b  But like I said, that gives a 404 when accessed.

Comment: @slolife, apparently, your intend use the combine script is neither supported nor recommended. See my edit in the answer.